# Need to have math operations among weights in the same dense layer unsing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer

So I guess I have a little unique problem (if it's been asked before, apologies as i didn't find it).

Let's say I have a neural network with dense layers, and in one particular layer, one of the weights from neuron a1 is w11, another weight from another neuron a2 is w21. I don't have biases.

In the subsequent layer, I need to have an output a1 X w11, a2 X w22 and so on, which is easy to do. However, I also need another output that gets a1 X a2 X w11 X w22.

In my mind, what I needed to achieve this is to have, in the previous layer, a weight called w11, a weight called w22, and another weight called w11 X w22, but I have been unable to find a way to put in math operations on the weights in this manner.

Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: Please, share your codes. Also, it is better to share image of your neural network structure.

Comment: i really don't have an image, & the research is unpublished so, i need to be a little careful with my details....... sorry but i'll do my best

i have an image shown in the url https://imgur.com/a/gompnUh.... the network above is an autoencoder, what i have at the moment..... whereas it takes the neurons at the bottleneck and multiplies by weights, i want the 2nd degree multiplications of them included in the reconstruction as well

did what i show in the image make sense? if it didn't, sorry and i'd be happy to elaborate further

Comment: i added a bit more context here in this image https://imgur.com/a/ELtoY2z...... basically, in the 1st (above) image, each neuron in the reconstruction output, was multiplying the neurons in the bottlenecks with their weights......... i need the neurons multipled, and the associated weights need to be products as well, in the way i tried to show in the image....... for 1st degree terms i would have certain weights, and for 2nd degree terms, i would need weights that are products of the weights associated with the 1st degree terms

Answer (score 0):

Try using **tensorflow** directly **low level api** - `tf.GradientTape`, as such **customization** is a straight forward in **low level api**, but in case of you **prefer** using **keras api**, then you can use `Lambda layer` which gives you access to the **output** of **any layer** in your network.

```
x0 = Dense(.....)(input)
x1 = Lambda(lambda x0_a: tf.math.sqrt(x0_a))(x0)
```

Or you may write your [Custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)

Some functions you might need to access weights `layer.get_weights ()`, `layer.set_weights ()`, and knowing about `custom callbacks` might be helpful too.

---

[Custom Weight Constraints](https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/#creating-custom-weight-constraints)

Comment: i'd like to ask something if i may........... if i take the output of a vector, and concatenate it with the pairwise products of the values in the array....... i might be able to do it with a lambda layer, but it seems i can simply do it with a mathmatical operation in numpy, and use tf.convert_to_tensor...... when using mini batch, it would be a matrix operation basically............ would that be possible, or would lambda layer be necessary to make that happen?

Comment: You can't apply a mathematical operation using numpy, to a layer object, therefore, I recommend you to write your Custom layer or use low level api, as i am not sure if you can access model weights using Lambda Layer if you just need the output tensor then using Lambda Layer is the best thing to do so.